# trying to enable_load_extension in sqlite for tcl

Tags: sqlite, tcl

classic case of getting bogged down in technical stuff when learning a new language. nothing to see here...

I'm trying to `enable_load_extension` in tcl and get "invalid command name "dbHandle"" as an error message. The traditional `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` query at the end works perfectly, I can't see what the problem is.

Perhaps compile options? the `PRAGMA compile_options;` call comes back with `COMPILER=msvc-1900 ENABLE_FTS3 ENABLE_RTREE THREADSAFE=1` Given that I'm not seeing `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` 
 (https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_load_extension) I should be ok?

sqlite3_db_config with `SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION` 
 looks useful, see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_config.html and https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbconfig_enable_fkey.html but these don't seem to be part of the tcl interface.

```
package require sqlite3

sqlite3 dbhandle example.db
puts [dbhandle eval {PRAGMA compile_options;}]

# $dbHandle enable_load_extension 1 ; #can't read "dbHandle": no such variable
# dbHandle enable_load_extension 1 ;   #invalid command name "dbHandle"
# dbHandle enable_load_extension true ;   #invalid command name "dbHandle"

# next line is fine
puts [dbhandle eval {SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';}]
```

Comment: You can't rely on the `SQLITE_OMIT_*` compile options being meaningful, because they are generally unsupported.

Comment: `$dbHandle` doesn't work since `dbHandle` isn't a variable name. `dbHandle` doesn't work since there is a case difference from `dbhandle`.

Comment: duh! too busy looking tcl errors, thanks for putting me right.